# Bug in Mathematica's Integrate with PrincipalValue->True

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

It seems that Mathematica's handling of principal value integrals fails on some corner cases. Consider these two expressions (which should give the same result):

```
Integrate[UnitBox[x]/(x0 - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
  PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> {x0 > 0}] /. x0 -> 1 // Simplify
Integrate[UnitBox[x]/(x0 - x) /. x0 -> 1, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]
```

In Mathematica 7.0.0 I get

```
I Pi+Log[3]
Log[3]
```

Has this been fixed in later versions? Does anybody have an idea for a (more or less) general workaround?

EDIT: The two expressions above should calculate the same result, the first by calculating a general form of the integral and evaluating it at `x0=1`, the second by performing the  integral with `x0` set to `1`. Since the Cauchy principal value has a precise mathematical definition, Mathematica should give the same result or decline to answer.

EDIT 2: A perhaps simpler example of the same bug, putting a factor of -1 inside and outside the `Integral` give different answers (second one gives the correct answer, first one doesn't):

```
-Integrate[ UnitBox[x]/(x0 - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> {x0 > 0}]
 Integrate[-UnitBox[x]/(x0 - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> {x0 > 0}]
```

Comment: As pointed out by brainfsck below, this is fixed in v8.

Comment: Janus, at mathematica.stackexchange.com we just got a migrated question from stackoverflow/mathematica. You was one of the answerers and we noticed that you haven't registered yet there. We'd appreciate if you, as one of the SO/MMA regulars, would register at mathematica.stackexchange.com as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug in `PrincipalValue`. In the first line `PrincipalValue` does not work "correctly" because the position of the pole is not known until after `Integrate` is done.

EDIT:
I played around in Mathematica a bit and this is exactly what happens. You can see for yourself by using the [`Trace[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) command. The output is a bit messy (which is why I don't replicate it here), but you can see where the integration gets done and where the value for `x0` is substituted and how that messes with `PrincipalValue`.

EDIT2:
So back to solving your actual problem. If you use an Assumption that specifies which side of x=1/2 x0 lies, then the two examples give the same answer.

Comment: From your answer, it appears that you consider  PrincipalValue as sort of a methods guidance for the integration algorithm, whereas I think of it as requesting a mathematically well defined result, namely the Cauchy principal value of the integral.  
 
As this result has a strict mathematical definition, it constitutes a bug (from my point of view) if Mathematica arrives at two different answers when asked for the result in two different (but mathematically equivalent) ways.

Comment: Well it is not strictly me who thinks of PrincipalValue that way, I'm just telling you how Mathematica behaves ;-). The question may be mathematically equivalent, but that does not mean that it is computationally equivalent or possible. Look at the output of Trace for both cases and think about what happens if x0->I. See how it becomes very difficult to decide on the principal value of the integral before the substitution?

Comment: I would also point out that the two ways are not mathematically equivalent. As you point out, the first integral is evaluated with x0 as a free parameter. Now my math is slightly rusty, but that seems to disqualify the integral from being a definite integral and thus make it impossible to select the Cauchy principal value even in a purely mathematical sense.

Comment: I don't quite agree on the mathematical equivalence -- but instead of continuing that discussion (without MathML), I have added another example of the bug to the question. For the new example I hope that we can agree that Mathematica spits out different results to exactly the same question?

As flipping the sign fixes the problem in all the situations I need it, I wont be examining this much more -- at the price Wolfram charges, they should certainly do their own bughunting!

Comment: OK, that's a bug! For an even better demonstration remove the `Assumptions->{x0>0}` part.

Comment: So back to solving your actual problem. If you use an Assumption that specifies which side of x=1/2 x0 lies, then the two examples give the same answer.

Comment: Thanks Timo. In my case, I don't know x0 -- the real motivation is that I want an expression that's valid for all values, preferably without a cases statement.
After flipping the sign on the integrand, I now get the answer I need, so all is peachy (my best guess is that `PrincipalValue` just looks for simple poles, and that the pattern is not clever enough). 
Anyways, I'll mark this as an answer to close the question.

Comment: Thanks. On a final note, flipping the sign actually does what I was suggesting since the assumption x0>0 puts x0 squarely on one side of x=-1/2 (note the sign change). The problem as far as I can determine is that if it is possible for the pole to be at x=1/2 (or -1/2 if you flip x's sign), this messes up Mathematicas logic for finding the principal value. Also, note that flipping the sign changes the problem in as much that the Assumption should read x0<0 now for the problem to be equivalent. This of course brings back the original problem :-(.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fixed in 8.0:

```
In[1]:= $Version
Out[1]= "8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit) (November 13, 2010)"

In[2]:= 
Integrate[UnitBox[x]/(x0 - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> {x0 > 0}] /. 
  x0 -> 1 // Simplify

Out[2]= Log[3]

In[3]:= Integrate[
 UnitBox[x]/(x0 - x) /. x0 -> 1, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]

Out[3]= Log[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Wolfram Alpha, which I would assume uses the latest version of Mathematica, doesn't like your first expression and gives this for the second:
log(3)+constant

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[UnitBox[x]%2F%28x0+-+x%29+%2F.+x0+-%3E+1%2C+{x%2C+-Infinity%2C+Infinity}%2C++++PrincipalValue+-%3E+True]

It may be that this article applies in this case but I'm not a math expert so I wouldn't know?
There are some situations, however, where several different answers are all equally consistent with the formal mathematical definitions. Thus, for example, in computing symbolic integrals, there are often several different expressions which all yield the same derivative. [Which of these expressions is actually generated by Integrate  can then depend on how Integrate  works inside.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that Wolfram Alpha doesn't understand the `Replace` and `Rule` syntax from standard Mathematica, so I am not quite sure what question it is answering.